# Appending data to a similar line using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have data in a file that looks like following:

```
field11|field12|field13
field11|field12|field23
field11|field32|field33
field41|field42|field43
field41|field52|field43
field41|field62|field63
```

As you see I have 2 id's `field11` and `field41` and I want them to appear only once so that it that looks like this:

```
field11|{'field12','field32'}|field13
field41|{'field42','field52','field62'}|field43
```

I want the third field to be same as the first appearance for that id. Each id($1) has different $3 while first or first and second field remain same. But i need to print whatever comes in first line for that id. As shown in the example we are printing field13 not field23.

I am trying to achieve this with `awk`/`sed`. I know a solution to do this with basic loops in shell. but I need to do this in `awk` or some similar tool.

Comment: Can the third field vary while the first remains constant, eg `field11|field12|field13` and `field11|field22|field33`? If so, please amend your example to show how this should be represented. If not, please amend your question to state this explicitly.

Comment: yes the third field varies while the first remains constant. thank you

Answer (score 0):

A slightly long (but hopefully easy to follow) `awk` solution:

```
BEGIN       { FS = OFS = "|" }

function output() {
    if (FNR == 1) return
    data = ""
    for (i in col2) {
        qi   = sprintf("'%s'", i);
        data = (data == "" ? qi : data "," qi)
    }
    print col1, sprintf("{%s}", data), col3
}

$1 == col1 && !($2 in col2) { col2[$2] }

$1 != col1    {
    output()
    col1 = $1; col3 = $3
    delete col2; col2[$2]
}

END { output() }
```

The `BEGIN` block just sets the input and output field separator to `|`.

The function `output()` will take the data collected in `col1` (the ID in the first column), `col2` (an array of unique data form the second column) and `col3` (the first data item for this particular ID from the third column) and output it.  It iterates over the keys in `col2`, quoting them individually and adding them with commas in-between to the string variable `data`. It then prints `col1`, `data` (within braces), and `col3`.

The next block executes when we find an entry in the second column that we haven't seen before for this particular ID. It just adds the second column as a key in `col2`.

The block after that executes when we find a new ID in the first column.  It calls `output()` and then resets the collected variables to start collecting data for this new ID.

In the `END` block, we call `output()` to output the data for the last ID.

This program will not try to store the whole file in memory at once, but requires that the data is sorted on the first column.

Running it on the provided data:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
field11|{'field12','field32'}|field13
field41|{'field42','field62','field52'}|field43
```

Answer (score 0):

A gnarly bit of perl:

```
perl -F'\|' -lane '
    $f2{ $F[0] }{ $F[1] } = 1;
    $f3{ $F[0] } = $F[2] if not exists $f3{ $F[0] }; 
  } END {
    for $key (sort keys %f2) {
        printf "%s|{%s}|%s\n", 
            $key, 
            join(",", map {chr(39) . $_ . chr(39)} sort keys %{$f2{$key}}), 
            $f3{$key};
    }
' file
```

The first 2 lines accumulate the data using associative arrays.
Then the END block loops over the data, formats and prints.